# Password protected database SQL Server with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010, ssms

we launched new SQL Server on AWS. Everything looks great, I can access the server via SSMS. However, I can't set up new credentials for one specific database. 
This database should be accessible via MS Access. It works in MS Access, when admin login and password, but I would like to give the users access only to the specific database.

I read this article and I guess I should created SQL user with password: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017

Unfortunately, I do not see this option in SSMS.
Don't you have any idea please, why it is so?

So my comprehensive requirement: 
 1. I need to set up password protected database. 
 2. This database will serve linked tables for MS Access.

Thank you very much for help,

Vaclav

[image: SSMS options by user creation]

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution. My login didn't have an appropriate server rights. To create a new user and define his permissions you have to "Server role" - securityadmin assigned to your login.

It is described here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017

Best regards,

Vaclav

Comment: In addition, [this link](https://www.sqlshack.com/contained-databases-in-sql-server/) helped too as there are some server instance level settings and database settings that need to be set as well.